# Отправить данные js (get)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, get

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="текст" hidden>
<a href="/delete.php?id=">Отправить</a>
```

Как взять данные из input и отправить в ссылку?
post и get формы не подходят.
Возможно выполнить post запрос с помощью ajax?
Как выполнить post или get запрос с помощью ajax без `<form></form>`?
Эти данные `/delete.php` должны быть скрыты.

Comment: Так как вы хотите получить данные, через $_GET или $_POST?

Comment: @doox911 если это можно без тегов <form></form> то да

Comment: да можно. Я и спрашиваю каким методом? Если хотите скрыть передачу данных, то надо передавать через post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что вы хотите, то примерно так.

```js
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", function(){
let value = document.getElementById("data").value;
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "/delete.php?id=" + value, true);
xhttp.send();
});
```

```html
<input id="data" type="text" name="id" value="текст" hidden>
<a href='#' id="send">Отправить</a>
```

Comment: Почему то кнопка не активна

Comment: Сделайте не тег <a>, a button. Я поправил в ответе.

Comment: Смотрите, суть заключается в том что нужно перейти по данной ссылке с значением input, где потом данные php забирает.

Comment: То есть надо и по ссылке перейти и чтоб там ссылки этой не было? Или просто надо нажать, чтоб данные отправились на бэк?

Comment: Нужно перейти по ссылке и что бы этой ссылки не было.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно через ajax.

```
$.ajax({
     method: "POST/GET", // Выберите нужный метод
     url: "/delete.php",
     data: {data = $('input').val()},
     success: function(result){
      alert(result);
        }
   });
```

Comment: И важно не забыть подключить jQuery ;)

Comment: Подскажите, как вызвать данную функцию?

Comment: Вызвать функцию можно на любое событие например нажатие на кнопку $('button').click(function(){ $.ajax(...) })